# Java - environment PATH variable doesn't include /usr/local/bin when using Process

Tags: java

In my Java application, I want to execute a python script with Process class. This python script needs to execute svn command. It seems that the PATH variable in my java application doesn't include `/usr/local/bin`. While I installed SVN 1.7.9 with homebrew and it's in /usr/local/bin. In the `/usr/bin` folder, there is another svn installed by xcode whose version is 1.6.x. This leads to a serious problem: when I execute the python script in my Java application, this script then executes svn in /usr/bin which is version 1.6.x. This version is too old to manage my working copy.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: You may want to use [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) instead and set the `PATH` envionment in such a way that `/usr/local/bin` get picked first. See the example in the javadoc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either set the `PATH` environment variable *before* you launch your (parent) Java application, or use [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).  The latter allows you to control what the child processes environment will contain via the `Map` object returned by the [`ProcessBuilder.environment()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#environment%28%29) method.

(But note that you typically can't change the contents of the child processes environment once it has been started ...)